# Rigid body following path

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I'm trying to make a rigid body sphere follow a path while it rests on another rigid body, which I'm tilting in different directions in order to balance the sphere, but I'm not having much success after several failed attempts. It ends up staying in the same place, like the image below, unless I manually keyframe the path but then it instead ignores the physics.

[image]

If I remove the path constraint and just treat it as a rigid body, it does react to the tilting plane below but quickly ends up rolling off the plane due to the physics, even if I only rotate the plane along one axis. I also want to be able to loop this which is another reason I want to try and solve this by applying a path constraint.
Is it possible to solve this in some way without having to manually keyframe everything? Any help would mean a lot to me.

Here is a link to the blend file if it helps: https://pasteall.org/blend/0f5d12df4024418d935c5e435661f760

Comment: it's not clear this part: "make a rigid body sphere follow a path while it rests on another rigid body". Do you have a reference video of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Do you just want the ball to roll back and forth?

Comment: you can only have one thing at a time: physics OR animated. you can change this behaviour per frame, but you can never have that at the same time

Comment: Yup, I want it to roll back and forth - but in a rather straight path. I realise I would probably have to keyframe this manually in order for this to work. Thanks so much for the clarification as well, Chris!

Answer (score 1):

just clear that "animated" checkbox in your sphere and it works.

[image]

result:

[image]